# set component params in storybook

Tags: javascript, angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I have created a simple story in angular, but the story params don't show up in the component.
Story:

```
export const myStory = (args: FileExplorerComponent) => ({
    component: FileExplorerComponent,
      template: `
        <div style="position: relative">
        <common-file-explorer></common-file-explorer>
            <p>Przykładowe użycie Webdav</p>
        </div>
        `,
         directory: 'bip',
         parameters: {
        directory: 'bip',
      },
      props: {
        directory: 'bip',
      menuItems: [
  { directory: 'bip' }
],
}
```

Component:

```
 @Input() directory: string;
```

Constructor:

```
console.log('directory', this.directory);
```

It shows undefined. Do I have to set up providers or constructor arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, shouldn't it be:

```
 template: `
<div style="position: relative">
   <common-file-explorer [directory]="this.directory" ></common-file-explorer>
   <p>Przykładowe użycie Webdav</p>
</div>
`,
```

?
Or possibly

```
 template: `
<div style="position: relative">
   <common-file-explorer [directory]="this.menuItems[0].directory" ></common-file-explorer>
   <p>Przykładowe użycie Webdav</p>
</div>
`,
```